# What datatype is this, val one = (1,2,3)

Tags: scala

Did some examples... on Scala's REPL.

I totally forgot to type `Array` when instantiating an Array object (trying to test ++ operator).

Anyway, now I'm wondering what datatype is this?

```
val one = (1,2,3)
```

Or what data structure or container is the code above? What is this call? Why is it useful? I don't believe the REPL gave any useful information on what the above code is.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is special syntax for constructing a `Tuple3` object. It's equivalent to

```
val one = Tuple3[Int, Int, Int](1, 2, 3)
```

Tuples are defined up to `Tuple22`. One important use case for tuples is returning multiple values from a function. Tuples can also be unpacked with special syntax:

```
scala> val (a, b, c) = one
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
```

Comment: Note, that there is nothing special about the syntax of unpacking. It is a straightforward pattern matching.

Comment: @agilesteel : Yes, it's pattern matching. The syntax for pattern matching of Tuples gets it's own section (8.1.7, Tuple Patterns) of the Scala Language Specification.

Comment: Note that starting with Scala 2.9, you can ask for the type of an expression in the REPL.
`scala> :type (1,"2",true)` gives `(Int, java.lang.String, Boolean)`.

Answer (score 7):

This is an instance of [Tuple3](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple3.html). Tuples can be thought of as fixed-sized immutable array where each element might have a different, static, compile-time checked type.

In your example this is precisely:

```
Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]
```

But you can create tuples of various types as well:

```
val one = (1, false, "a")
```

In this case:

```
one._1    // 1, Int type
one._2    // false, Boolean
one._3    // "a", String
```

Tuples have various use cases. They are mostly used to return two values (less often more) from a function. You could use an array or list, but then all elements need to be of the same type (`Any` in the worst case), so you loose static-type checking. Also there is no guarantee of the size of such a sequence, whilst tuple has a fixed size, known at compile time.

Treat tuples as lightweight, temporary objects, but not abuse them. For instance don't use `Tuple3` to represent day/month/year.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]

```
val one = (1,2,3) 
val two = Tuple3(1, 2, 3)
two == one // true
```